# Different Browser behaviour on HTTP 302

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I encountered a web form today which works for Firefox but not chromium (tested Edge and Chrome).
The form action leads to a HTTP 302, after that another 302, and then finally 200 - at least with Firefox and Fiddler and Rested (brower addon). However, when trying with chromium it's just plain 404 Not found. I double checked all headers and parameters, it's the same for both.
I tried to document what I saw.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6B1.jpg - working in Rested
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoBnv.jpg - whatever chromium is doing

Do I have to call the people responsible for the form or is there any browser setting I am not aware of?

Comment: Have you tested other browsers and will the same issue occur? Try clearing the browser cache, this might help.

Comment: @XudongPeng I tested Chrome, Edge, Opera, Firefox and even IE on 3 different devices. No Edge, Chrome or opera worked. FireFox and IE did. I also tried clearing browser data. However the result was still the same.

Comment: If this is the case, I recommand you could report this issue to relvant team via this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).